# Automatic delopyment to Azure Web App from VSO

Tags: visual-studio, azure-web-app-service, continuous-deployment

I have the code for a website sitting in Visual Studio Online (VSO) with automatic build. This works fine.

I would also like the web site to be pushed to a Azure Web App upon successful build.

I have set up a service hook to my Azure subscription and when I add an "Azure Web App deployment" step, I am asked to configure it.

But it asks me in "Web deploy package" to provide the path to the artifacts location.

[image]

So the questions are:

1. What is the path to the default artifact directory?
2. Do I need to set up the build to package the web site in a
   particular way first-hand? If so - how?

Thanks,

/Jesper

Comment: Where you ever able to get this resolved?

Comment: Hey @JoeRaio well, I took the liberty of asking the same question over on MSDN Forums, and that thread kind of spiralled out of control. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b383f9fc-c55e-4abe-9348-25ed8bb69e9c/automatic-delopyment-to-azure-web-app-from-vso?forum=TFService . I got the automatic deployment to work with the built-in "Deployment / Azure Web App" - build step. Now my problems are with VSO :-). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in setting up continues deployment from VSO I have not seen that screen you are referring to. Have you tried following the instructions found here: [Continuous Delivery with Visual Studio Online in Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-continuous-delivery-use-vso/)

This is the method I have always used. It walks you through step by step and works perfect for me. Hope this helps!